# What is dataEncapsulation Option in HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot?

Tags: angular

What does dataEncapsulation option do in HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot?

I found the below code in Angular Tutorial/HTTP session.

```js
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
        InMemoryDataService, { dataEncapsulation: false }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the [**`InMemoryBackendConfigArgs`**](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/a94855b7e11ad11f852b0ac7bc0987e25635658e/interfaces.d.ts#L49):

> false (default) put content directly inside the response body.
>
> true: encapsulate content in a `data` property inside the response body, `{ data: ... }`.

So you set `dataEncapsulation` to true, your data will be present in a property named `data` on the response.

That's also something that the [**Unit Tests**](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/a94855b7e11ad11f852b0ac7bc0987e25635658e/src/in-mem/http-client-backend.service.spec.ts#L660) check for:

```
describe('Http dataEncapsulation = true', () => {
  let http: HttpClient;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        HttpClientModule,
        HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(HeroInMemDataService, {
          delay,
          dataEncapsulation: true
        })
      ]
    });

    http = TestBed.get(HttpClient);
  });

  it('can get heroes (encapsulated)', async(() => {
    http.get < Data > ('api/heroes').pipe(
      map(data => data.data as Hero[]) // unwrap data object. SINCE `dataEncapsulation` was set to `true`
    ).subscribe(
      heroes => {
        expect(heroes.length).toBeGreaterThan(0, 'should have data.heroes');
      },
      failure
    );
  }));

});
```